# Error: The default value of an optional parameter must be constant

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting an error when assigning a default value to an instance variable of the type Color. I'm getting this error only when I assign colors with their shade value.

***Error: The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.***

```
class CardPanelHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  final String leadingPanelText;
  final Color leadingPanelTextColor;
  final String trailingPanelText;
  final Color trailingPanelTextColor;

  const CardPanelHeader({
    Key key,
    this.leadingPanelText,
    this.leadingPanelTextColor = Colors.black87,
    this.trailingPanelText,
    this.trailingPanelTextColor = Colors.grey.shade600,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

I did check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279223/flutter-default-assignment-of-list-parameter-in-a-constructor) but didn't work for me.

Could anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56489812/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use absolute value of the color as constant value; change the `Colors.grey.shade600` to `const Color(0xFF757575)` you can find the hex code of colors https://material.io/resources/color/